# Editing the cart/checkout in Woocommerce now hooks no longer work?

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Woocommerce has moved the cart/checkout into blocks instead of using shortcodes, which means you can no longer hook into the template to change things.

I know I could go back to using the shortcode but that stops all of the Ajax functionality working. I want to edit the Empty Cart information specifically (without having to use the template files) but so far unable to find a way of doing it. Any advice?